# XCode 5 seems to delete InstallationBuildProductsLocation for Archive

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I have a workspace that contains multiple projects. Some projects get packaged as frameworks and then there is one main project that is the iOS app itself. The main app references the frameworks. This was working in Xcode 4.6 when building and archiving but it is no longer working in Xcode 5 for several reasons that seem to be related to Xcode 5 using different build paths.  I have worked through most of these issues (I hope) but I have one issue remaining.

One of my targets for my framework projects has a target set up that only contains only a .storyboard file - it is set to compile this one storyboard file. A regular build seems to work fine but when I do an archive on this specific target the `InstallationBuildProductsLocation` folder where the .bundle file for the storyboard gets created is deleted after the target completes. The following commands are executed according to the log:

[image: log screenshot]

But after this has completed successfully the `InstallationBuildProductsLocation` is no longer there.  I have verified that it is initially getting created by inserting a Run Script after the Compile Sources build phase that throws an error - which causes the archive to not completed and in this case the directory and .bundle file are left intact.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and is there a way to prevent Xcode 5 from deleting this directory? I guess, my alternative is to copy the bundle to another location before it gets deleted so that I can use it later on when I package it in a framework.

Comment: I am also having this problem while creating a static library framework for ios.  Did you ever figure this out or find a work-around?

Comment: I ended up copying the bundle to a "safe" location before Xcode had a chance to delete it. Did this in a custom script that I added in as a build phase.

Answer (score 3):

When you archive, the result (an .xcarchive file) is in a different directory -- ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives -- where archives are stored by date.

Comment: is it possible to override this behaviour ? or at least, to make the command print the "moving phase" into logs/console ? I am trying to make Jenkins Xcode plugin work, and stuck on this so far

Comment: @62mkv `-archivePath` does what you need. `xcodebuild archive -scheme s0 -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos -derivedDataPath build/derivedData -archivePath archives/Release-iphoneos.xcarchive`

Comment: that is quite a flashback  :) nothing gets forgotten on the internet! :))))